# Compilation Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting name of variable

Tags: solidity, compilation, warnings

I am getting a compilation error

```
Warning: Unnamed return variable can remain unassigned. Add an explicit return with value to all non-reverting code paths or name the variable.
  --> contracts/contract.sol:91:61:
   |
91 |     function isApproved(address user) external view returns(bool) {
   |                                                             ^^^^
```

The function returns a bool value stored in the struct Transaction which is stored in a mapping. The function is :

```
function isApproved(address user) external view returns(bool) {
        for ( uint256 i = 0; i < transactionId; i++) {
            if (transactions[i].user == user && transactions[i].isApproved) {
                return transactions[i].isApproved;
            }
        }
    }
```

The mapping and the struct is

```
mapping(uint256 => Transaction) public transactions;

    struct Transaction {
        address user;
        uint256 amount;
        bool isDeposit;
        bool isApproved;
    }
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a return value in case all isApproveds are false:

```
function isApproved(address user) external view returns(bool) {
    for ( uint256 i = 0; i < transactionId; i++) {
        if (transactions[i].user == user && transactions[i].isApproved) {
            return true; // no use in returning transactions[i].isApproved, because the code can only come here when that's true.
        }
    }
    // without the following line, there's no return value sometimes and that's why there was an error.
    return false; // if all isApproveds are false, return false.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name your return variable, and do

```
                                     // This implicitely sets the 
                                     // default return value to false
function isApproved(address user) external view returns(bool approved) {
        for ( uint256 i = 0; i < transactionId; i++) {
            if (transactions[i].user == user && transactions[i].isApproved) {
                approved = transactions[i].isApproved;
            }
        }
    }
```

Actually, I'm not 100% certain of what i'm saying (if anyone can confirm or deny, that'd be awesome) but i believe your current code would lead to undefined behavior if the if statement never evaluates to true (it would return whatever data is in the memory at that point) which is about the worst thing that could happen in a smart contract, so yeah, fix that.